# Mocking external class method inside React component with jest

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to test component method, which inside performing network call to external resources. After reading docs I still can't figure out how to do so. Can anyone help? Here is my code(some parts hidden for brevity):

My component:

```
import React from 'react'
import ResourceService from '../../modules/resource-service'

export default class SliderComponent extends React.Component {
  setActiveSlide = (activeSlide) => {
    ResourceService.getData({
      id: activeSlide,
    }).then((data) => {
      if (data) {
        this.setState({
          data,
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Resource service:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default class ResourceService {
  static getData(params) {
    return axios.post('/api/get_my_data', params)
      .then((resp) => resp.data)
  }
}
```

Desired test (as I understand it):

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount, configure } from 'enzyme'
import SliderComponent from '../../../app/components/slider'

test('SliderComponent changes active slide when setActiveSlide is  
called', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <SliderComponent />
  );
  wrapper.instance().setActiveSlide(1);
  // some state checks here
});
```

I need mock `ResourceService.getData` call inside `SliderComponent`, and I really can't understand ho to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import your `ResourceService` in your test and mock the method `getData` with `jest.fn(() => ...)`. Here is an example:

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount, configure } from 'enzyme'
import ResourceService from '../../../modules/resource-service'
import SliderComponent from '../../../app/components/slider'

test('SliderComponent changes active slide when setActiveSlide is  
called', () => {
   // you can set up the return value, you can also resolve/reject the promise 
   // to test different scnarios
   ResourceService.getData = jest.fn(() => (
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve({ data: "testData" }); }));

  const wrapper = mount(<SliderComponent />);

  wrapper.instance().setActiveSlide(1);

  // you can for example check if you service has been called
  expect(ResourceService.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
  // some state checks here
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it's exactly what I needed.
A didn't try this approach, instead trying to create mock ResouceService class in __mocks__ folder...

Comment: No probs, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

try using [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter) to mock the postreq in your test.

It should look something like this (may need a few more tweaks):

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount, configure } from 'enzyme'
import SliderComponent from '../../../app/components/slider'
import axios from'axios';
import MockAdapter = from'axios-mock-adapter';

test('SliderComponent changes active slide when setActiveSlide is  
called', () => {
let mock = new MockAdapter(axios)
//you can define the response you like
//but your params need to be accordingly to when the post req gets called
 mock.onPost('/api/get_my_data', params).reply(200, response) 

  const wrapper = mount(
    <SliderComponent />
  );
  wrapper.instance().setActiveSlide(1);
  // some state checks here
});
```

make sure to check the docs of axios-mock-adapter

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I prefer not to use additional modules where it's possible. And native Jest solution, proposed above by margaretkru perfectly fit my needs.